# Tkinter - How to display image when clicking a button?

Tags: python, tkinter

First time here so forgive me as this is my FIRST attempt at making a silly GUI game (if you want to call it that). I'm trying to get the user to click a button and the image of their selection pops up. I can't seem to figure out how to get the image to pop up though.

Image does show if I run it separately.

My code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class PokemonClass(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.WelcomeLabel = Label(root, text="Welcome! Pick your Pokemon!",
                                  bg="Black", fg="White")
        self.WelcomeLabel.pack(fill=X)

        self.CharButton = Button(root, text="Charmander", bg="RED", fg="White",
                                 command=self.CharClick)
        self.CharButton.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

        self.SquirtButton = Button(root, text="Squirtle", bg="Blue", fg="White")
        self.SquirtButton.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

        self.BulbButton = Button(root, text="Bulbasaur", bg="Dark Green",
                                 fg="White")
        self.BulbButton.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

    def CharClick(self):
        print "You like Charmander!"
        global CharSwitch
        CharSwitch = 'Yes'

CharSwitch = 'No'

if CharSwitch == 'Yes':
    CharPhoto = PhotoImage(file="Charmander.gif")
    ChLabel = Label(root, image=CharPhoto)
    ChLabel.pack()

k = PokemonClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is this the correct indentation? Strikes me that you didn't intend the part that sets the image to be run straight away. It will never run as you just set the value to `no`. You should move that code to be within the button callback.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but the actual image no longer shows, if I keep the PhotoImage OUT of the class it will print but I want to have it print IF they click the specific button:

```
from Tkinter import *



root = Tk()


class PokemonClass(object):

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.WelcomeLabel = Label(root, text = "Welcome! Pick your Pokemon!", bg = "Black", fg = "White")
        self.WelcomeLabel.pack(fill = X)

        self.CharButton = Button(root, text = "Charmander", bg = "RED", fg = "White", command = CharClick)
        self.CharButton.pack(side = LEFT, fill = X)

        self.SquirtButton = Button(root, text = "Squirtle", bg = "Blue", fg = "White")
        self.SquirtButton.pack(side = LEFT, fill = X)

        self.BulbButton = Button(root, text = "Bulbasaur", bg = "Dark Green", fg = "White")
        self.BulbButton.pack(side = LEFT, fill = X)

    def CharClick():
    print "You like Charmander!"
    CharPhoto = PhotoImage(file = "Charmander.gif")
    ChLabel = Label(root, image = CharPhoto)
    ChLabel.pack()


k = PokemonClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This should be an edit to your question, rather than an answer. I think your issue is explained here http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm or a potentially more up to date source http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/PhotoImage

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a reference to your `PhotoImage` object. Unfortunately there is an inconsistency in tkinter in that attaching a `Button` to a parent widget increments the reference count, but adding an image to a widget does not increment the reference count. As a consequence at the moment the `CharPhoto` variable goes out of scope at the end of the function `CharClick`, the number of reference to the `PhotoImage` falls to zero and the object is made available for garbage collection.

If you keep a reference to the image somewhere, it will appear. When you kept it globally it remained in scope for the entire script and hence appeared.

You can keep a reference to it in the `PokemonClass` object or in the `Label` widget.

Below is the later of those options

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class PokemonClass(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.WelcomeLabel = Label(root, text="Welcome! Pick your Pokemon!",
                                  bg="Black", fg="White")
        self.WelcomeLabel.pack(fill=X)

        self.CharButton = Button(root, text="Charmander", bg="RED", fg="White",
                                 command=self.CharClick)
        self.CharButton.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

        self.SquirtButton = Button(root, text="Squirtle", bg="Blue", fg="White")
        self.SquirtButton.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

        self.BulbButton = Button(root, text="Bulbasaur", bg="Dark Green",
                                 fg="White")
        self.BulbButton.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

    def CharClick(self):
        print "You like Charmander!"
        global CharSwitch
        CharSwitch = 'Yes'
        CharPhoto = PhotoImage(file="Charmander.gif")
        ChLabel = Label(root, image=CharPhoto)
        ChLabel.img = CharPhoto
        ChLabel.pack()

CharSwitch = 'No'

k = PokemonClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution which helped me is just simply declaring all the image variables on the next line after 'root = Tk()'. Doing so won't spoil your code or anything.